# How to read OpenOffice.org text document

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, openoffice.org

On my system I don't have Microsoft Office installed so as an alternative I am using OpenOffice.Org. Using this source how do I read a text document in ASP.NET using the C# language?

Comment: did you do a search on this website? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511216/openoffice-with-net-how-to-iterate-throught-all-paragraphs-and-read-text

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your wording correctly, you're looking to read an Open Office Writer file  using C# and ASP.NET

If so, I'd suggest you read up on the file structure:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification

Here is a more complete specification
http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/12572/OpenDocument-v1.0-os.pdf

And here is a free book on the matter
http://books.evc-cit.info/

If you're just looking to extract textual data from a writer document, then it's just an XML file in a ZIP container, so presumably you'd just want to get the content from a specific tag and flatten it, stripping the styling tags from within it.

Comment: Hi Jordaan Mylonas thanks 4 reply......if u have code for that plz send me its very urgent 4 me right nw...when am feel free i will read that document...

Comment: Code for what, specifically? What is your exact intent?